# checking information of different computers in a network using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script to access a file (nodeNames) that contains ip addresses to different computers in a cluster network, `ssh` into each of these computers and output some basic information namely: Hostname, Host IPaddress, load average and the process using the most memory and append all these information into a file seperating each wit commas. Also, each of the computers have same user and password. This is my code so far but it isn't working, please I need help here

```
egrep -ve '^#|^$'nodeNames | while read a
do
ssh $a "$@" &
output1=`hostname`

#This will display the server's IP address
output2=`hostname -i`

#This will output the server's load average 
output3=`uptime  | grep -oP '(?<=average:).*'| tr -d ','`

#This outputs memory Information
output4=`ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=1{print $0}'`

#This concantenates all output to a single line of text written to 
echo "$output1, $output2, $output3, $output4" | tee clusterNodeInfo
done
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post what is in `nodeNames` (at least 4-5 lines). Presuming it is just hostnames, why not `[ -f "/path/to/nodeNames" ] || exit 1; hosts=( $( </path/to/nodeNames) ); for h in "${hosts[@]}"; do ... done`?

Comment: The `nodeNames` contains IP addresses with each address on a separate line for example:192.168.14.105
192.168.14.110
192.168.14.121
192.168.14.130

Comment: Ok, that loop setup will work fine. It loads all the IPs into the array `hosts` and then loops over host using the variable `h`. You should then `ssh "$h" "hostname -i; uptime | grep ..." >> yourfile` for each host to collect the info in `yourfile` on your local machine.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: `ssh "$h" "hostname -i; uptime | grep ..." >> yourfile` what do i need to `grep` to get the four information in my code and how do I output the information seperating each by commas to `myfile` @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: I also get this error when I try to run the command `./nodeDetails.sh: line 1: [-f: command not found`

Comment: I was simply going by what you have posted. No specific need for `grep`, but it looked like you were parsing some of the information that way. The key is simply sending the command to each host via `ssh` (using a heredoc makes sense) and then redirecting the output to a file. I do a lot of similar backup to a group of servers using the same array setup. That is a convenient way to loop over the list of filenames. You can also simply use your file of IPs to fee a `while` loop if you have no other need for the array (like getting a host-count before looping, etc..)

Comment: Need a space between `[` and `-f`.  `[` is actually a command: `/usr/bin/[`, and `-f` is a parameter to that command.

Comment: Anyway, if you have a bunch of hosts to manage, I strongly recommend `expect` and `ansible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand what is executed on which computer. The shell script you start is executed on your host A and you want information from your host B. `ssh $a "$@" &` will not suddenly make all the commands execute on the remote host B. Therefore, the

```
output1=`hostname`
```

will be executed on host A and `output1` will have the hostname of host A.

You may also want to put the `tee` outside the loop or use `tee -a` to prevent overwriting your output file.

For `bash`, use `$()` instead of `` .

So, that would make your script:

```
egrep -ve '^#|^$'nodeNames | while read a
do
    output1=$(ssh $a hostname)

    #This will display the server's IP address
    output2=$(ssh $a hostname -i)

    #This will output the server's load average 
    output3=$(ssh $a "uptime  | grep -oP '(?<=average:).*'| tr -d ','")

    #This outputs memory Information
    output4=$(ssh $a "ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=1{print $0}'")

    #This concantenates all output to a single line of text written to 
    echo "$output1, $output2, $output3, $output4" | tee -a  clusterNodeInfo
done
```

(have not tested it, but it should be something like this)

Comment: I tried running the code but it isn't working. I was wondering if it had anything to do with OpenSsh or authorization key

Comment: So try it step-by-step. Does ssh work (try `ssh remoteserver ls`)?  If not: fix ssh first. Then try `output1=$(ssh remote_hostname hostname) ; echo $output1` etcetera etceters.